# Reshape table with multiple columns in groups of 3 into table with 3 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, reshape

I have a data frame with multiple columns and multiple rows,
which looks like:

```
                V1       V2        V3         V4      V5       V6
  1             1         2         3         13      14       15
  2             4         5         6         16      NA       NA 
  3             7         8         9         19      20       21 
  4             10        11        12        22      23       24
```

And I want to reshape it into:

```
                V1       V2        V3       
  1             1         2         3         
  2             4         5         6         
  3             7         8         9         
  4             10        11        12       
  5             13        14        15
  6             16        NA        NA 
  7             19        20        21 
  8             22        23        24
```

In the original data.frame, keep every 3 columns as a group, such that (`V1`, `V2`, `V3`) is *group1*, (`V4`, `V5`, `V6`) is *group2*, etc. Then move *group2* - without the order of values changing - to the end of *group1*, and move *group3* to the end of *group2*.

I tried:

```
  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(mydata, use.names=FALSE), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
```

but have the value order problem.

How can I get my desired data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already noticed that `unlist` gives you the values column-wise:

```
unlist(df[1:3], use.names = FALSE)
##  [1]  1  4  7 10  2  5  8 11  3  6  9 12
```

To get the values row-wise, you can use the `c(t(...))` idiom:

```
c(t(df[1:3]))
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

That would allow you to solve the problem in base R using:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(c(t(df[1:3]), t(df[4:6])), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  4  5  6
## 3  7  8  9
## 4 10 11 12
## 5 13 14 15
## 6 16 NA NA
## 7 19 20 21
## 8 22 23 24
```

---

Generalized as a function, you can try something like:

```
splitter <- function(indf, ncols) {
  if (ncol(indf) %% ncols != 0) stop("Not the right number of columns to split")
  inds <- split(sequence(ncol(indf)), c(0, sequence(ncol(indf)-1) %/% ncols))
  temp <- unlist(lapply(inds, function(x) c(t(indf[x]))), use.names = FALSE)
  as.data.frame(matrix(temp, ncol = ncols, byrow = TRUE))
}
splitter(df, 3)
```

---

A more flexible "data.table" approach would be something like the following:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(split.default(as.data.table(df), 
                        c(0, sequence(ncol(df)-1) %/% 3)), 
          use.names = FALSE)
##    V1 V2 V3
## 1:  1  2  3
## 2:  4  5  6
## 3:  7  8  9
## 4: 10 11 12
## 5: 13 14 15
## 6: 16 NA NA
## 7: 19 20 21
## 8: 22 23 24
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried the last two code with my real-world large data frame, it works amazing!

Comment: @Duerna, Glad to help! `c` and `matrix` and so on should be very fast, and don't require any packages. `data.table` gives you the advantage of working with a large dataset....

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised that no one mentions `split.default`, which also works on data with more columns:

```
x <- split.default(df, ceiling(seq_along(df) / 3 ))
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, setNames, names(x[[1]])))

#     V1 V2 V3
# 1.1  1  2  3
# 1.2  4  5  6
# 1.3  7  8  9
# 1.4 10 11 12
# 2.1 13 14 15
# 2.2 16 NA NA
# 2.3 19 20 21
# 2.4 22 23 24
```

Add `make.row.names = FALSE` to get rid of the odd row names:

```
do.call(rbind, c(lapply(x, setNames, names(x[[1]])), list(make.row.names = FALSE)))
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  4  5  6
# 3  7  8  9
# 4 10 11 12
# 5 13 14 15
# 6 16 NA NA
# 7 19 20 21
# 8 22 23 24
```

Comment: `split.default` indeed makes sense here.

Comment: `split.default` also makes it really easy to use `data.table`....

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using `data.table`:-

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 7, 10), V2 = c(2, 5, 8, 11), V3 = c(3, 6, 9, 12), V4 = c(13, 16, 19, 22), V5 = c(14, NA, 20, 23), V6 = c(15, NA, 21, 24))


library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df1 <- df[, c("V4", "V5", "V6")]
setnames(df1, "V4", "V1")
setnames(df1, "V5", "V2")
setnames(df1, "V6", "V3")
df <- df[, c("V1", "V2", "V3")]
df <- rbind(df, df1)
```

Output will be:-

```
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  2  3
2:  4  5  6
3:  7  8  9
4: 10 11 12
5: 13 14 15
6: 16 NA NA
7: 19 20 21
8: 22 23 24
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I need a long code since I have 225 columns (75 groups X3).

Comment: @Duerna, I've edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917448/1270695) with a more flexible `data.table` approach.

Comment: @ A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Column, Value) %>%
  extract(Column, into = c("Group", "Index"), regex = "([A-Z+])([\\d].*$)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Index = Index %% 3) %>%
  mutate(Index = ifelse(Index == 0, 3, Index)) %>%
  unite(Column, c("Group", "Index"), sep = "") %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Column, Value) %>%
  select(-ID)
dt2
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#      V1    V2    V3
# * <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     2     3
# 2     4     5     6
# 3     7     8     9
# 4    10    11    12
# 5    13    14    15
# 6    16    NA    NA
# 7    19    20    21
# 8    22    23    24
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "              V1       V2        V3         V4      V5       V6
  1             1         2         3         13      14       15
                 2             4         5         6         16      NA       NA 
                 3             7         8         9         19      20       21 
                 4             10        11        12        22      23       24",
                 header = TRUE)
```

**Update**

Here is an example showing the code will also work on larger data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- as_data_frame(matrix(1:60, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE))

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Column, Value) %>%
  extract(Column, into = c("Group", "Index"), regex = "([A-Z+])([\\d].*$)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Index = Index %% 3) %>%
  mutate(Index = ifelse(Index == 0, 3, Index)) %>%
  unite(Column, c("Group", "Index"), sep = "") %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Column, Value) %>%
  select(-ID)
dt2
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#      V1    V2    V3
# * <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     2     3
#  2    13    14    15
#  3    25    26    27
#  4    37    38    39
#  5    49    50    51
#  6     4     5     6
#  7    16    17    18
#  8    28    29    30
#  9    40    41    42
# 10    52    53    54
# 11     7     8     9
# 12    19    20    21
# 13    31    32    33
# 14    43    44    45
# 15    55    56    57
# 16    10    11    12
# 17    22    23    24
# 18    34    35    36
# 19    46    47    48
# 20    58    59    60
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's works!

Comment: @Duerna Please see my updated post. I change the regex to be `([A-Z+])([\\d].*$)`. The reason is I believe the original code can only handle small data frames (column number smaller than 10), which is because the regex will create one digit index even if the original column names have more than one digits (`V11` to be `V1`, `V12` to be `V1`, ...). The new regex can capture that. I also added a data frame with 12 columns to show the code works.

Comment: thank you, I have run both code you provided with my original data, and all the two codes could get a result showed "A tibble: 44,400 x 7", it seems all code could handle large data frames. As for why the "dt2" show like  " x 7" , not " x 3", I think the reason is  my original data header, all the columns header contain same letter : " factor ,x, y" , like " factor1,x1,y1,factor2,x2,y2,factor3,x3,y3,..." . Anyway, thank you very much for you help.

Comment: @Duerna `([A-Z+])` is to capture upper case only, so it will not work on your real-world data frame. I did not know your header is more complex than your example data frame. I think for your real-world data, we can use `([A-Za-z].*)` to capture any letters.

Comment: Thank you. I will pay attention to describe my data frame. And I tried with ([A-Za-z].*), I got " A tibble: 2,368 x 73", the code captured 73 out of 75 from my real-world data header. The 1st and 2nd code you kindly provided works much better with my real-word data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution for any number of columns, using `dplyr`.

Test data `data`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 9
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
2    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
3    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
4    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36
5    37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45
```

The code:

```
for (i in seq(1, ncol(data), by = 3)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    out <- select(data, 1:3)
  } else {
    out <- select(data, i:(i+2)) %>% setNames(names(out)) %>% bind_rows(out, .)
  }
}
```

The output `out`:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
      V1    V2    V3
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     2     3
 2    10    11    12
 3    19    20    21
 4    28    29    30
 5    37    38    39
 6     4     5     6
 7    13    14    15
 8    22    23    24
 9    31    32    33
10    40    41    42
11     7     8     9
12    16    17    18
13    25    26    27
14    34    35    36
15    43    44    45
```

Comment: @Duerna Awesome!